# Seek for help, concavtity function

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to know suppose that i prove that 
$$
f_x^{''}(x,y)<0, \forall y, 
$$
and
$$f_y^{''}(x,y)<0, \forall x.
$$
If i can say that f(x,y) is concave? because, 
$$
f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)<f(x+\delta x,y)<f(x,y). 
$$

The test by hessain matrix is just suitable for certain point. I can't find any law for my problem. many thanks!!

Comment: I mean $$f^{''}_{xx}$$, and $$f^{''}_{yy}$$. It's a typo.

Comment: I downvoted because this question is more suitable for math.se. 
Anyway, consider $f(x) = x^T \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 10\\ 10 & -1\end{bmatrix}x$, the hessian of $f(x)$ is indefinite. This problem is non concave even though $f_{xx} = f_{yy} > 0$

Comment: thank you for the explaination. but as for your function, $$f=-x^2_1+20x_1x_2-x^2_2$$. it is also concave according to matlab simulation. i don't know how to add the picture here.

Comment: The restriction of $f$ to the diagonal $x_1=x_2$ is $18 x_1^2$...

Comment: Please accept my answer or indicate what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative, consider
$$f(x) = x^T \begin{pmatrix} -10 & 1 \\ 1 & -10 \end{pmatrix}x,$$
whose hessian is indefinite.